# SQL Syntax To Show Related Rows Under Each Other?

Tags: mysql

I have table for keeping user comments in it. This is how it looks like:

```
╔══════╦════════════╦═════════════════╦══════╦════════╗
║  ID  ║    Name    ║     Comment     ║  Re  ║  Time  ║
╠══════╬════════════╬═════════════════╬══════╬════════╣
║  1   ║    Jack    ║   Nice Movie!   ║  0   ║  8:12  ║
║  2   ║    Smith   ║ Agree With That ║  1   ║  8:30  ║
║  3   ║    Bob     ║     Terrible    ║  0   ║ 10:15  ║
║  4   ║    Bill    ║       Yep       ║  1   ║  8:22  ║
║  5   ║    Will    ║This Movie Rocks ║  4   ║  9:31  ║
╚══════╩════════════╩═════════════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

I want it to be like this:

```
╔══════╦════════════╦═════════════════╦══════╦════════╗
║  ID  ║    Name    ║     Comment     ║  Re  ║  Time  ║
╠══════╬════════════╬═════════════════╬══════╬════════╣
║  1   ║    Jack    ║   Nice Movie!   ║  0   ║  8:12  ║
║  4   ║    Bill    ║       Yep       ║  1   ║  8:22  ║
║  5   ║    Will    ║This Movie Rocks ║  4   ║  9:31  ║
║  2   ║    Smith   ║ Agree With That ║  1   ║  8:30  ║
║  3   ║    Bob     ║     Terrible    ║  0   ║ 10:15  ║
╚══════╩════════════╩═════════════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

As You see The first comments are reply to 0 and ordered by time and the others which replied to another message are placed under them and ordered by time.

how can i achieve something like this? thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**
I have three tables: **users**, **comments** and **posts**, Created with these queries:

**Users Table**

```
CREATE TABLE users(UID INT PRIMARY KEY, UName TEXT);
```

**UID:** user's id

**UName:** user's name

**Posts Table**

```
CREATE TABLE posts(PID INT PRIMARY KEY, PTitle TEXT, PBody TEXT, PDate DATETIME);
```

**PID:** post's id

**PTitle:** holds post's Title

**PBody:** post content

**PDate:** the date post was written

**Comments Table**

```
CREATE TABLE comments(CID INT PRIMARY KEY, UID INT, PID INT, Comment TEXT, Reply INT, CDate DATETIME);
```

**CID:** comment id

**UID:** the user id who commented this comment

**PID:** the post id that this comment is related with

**Comment:** the comment text

**Reply:** the comment id that this comment was replied to

**CDate:** the date comment was sent

Comment: the name could be anything. you mean edit the post and write same name in each row?? @Drew

Comment: the user table has Jack in it. the Comments table has his id in it via userId. Otherwise it is de-normalized

Comment: oh I see. this is a sample table. I absolutely do that in my real table.

Comment: @Code-Monk It's DateTime

Comment: ok. let me edit my post and write my sql queries for those tables

Comment: Here's a ready fiddle if someone wants to try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89745

Comment: @Drew is it better now?

Comment: The first block above says you have a table. The second block says you want it to look like this (meaning a query result?). Then you say under the second block `As You see The first comments are reply to 0 and ordered by time and the others which replied to another message are placed under them and ordered by time.` No I actually cant see that. I would improve the question

Comment: how should I improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You did not say whether you wanted a hierarchical display, in which it's possible to reply to replies, etc. That's a pain in the neck in pure MySQL. You'd be best off if you need that to structure your `Re` column somehow as a path to the parent.  (Or use a dbms capable of querying hierarchies.)

ASSUMING a one-level comment / reply display is good enough, you can try this. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b51ad/5/0). It transforms your `Re` column, which is zero for the origin comment of a thread, into a `Thread` column. It then orders by thread, and within thread by timestamp. That seems useful.

```
select case when re = 0 then id else re end thread,
       id, name, comment, re time
  from cmnt
 order by thread , time
```

Comment: really tricky answer!!! but its not what I was looking for. as you said replies may be replied too. but thanks for the `hierarchical` word. very helpful